# Mostrar <div> al clickear en un botón

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, script

Mi problema es que tengo un **popup** con un botón y quiero mostrar un texto que está dentro de un **div** pero al **clickearlo** no muestra nada.
En resumen éste es el código que tengo hasta el momento porque si lo motrara todo sería muy extenso.
 Gracias.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="mostrar()" class="add-to-cart" value="Añadir a compra" />

    </form>
    <div id="alerta">
        <p>Su articulo se ha anadido</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#alerta{
    margin-top:1 0px;
    display: none;
}

#alerta p{
    color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

**Script**

```
function mostrar() {
    var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: para que `.style` te regrese un valor este tuvo que haber sido seteado anteriormente de forma dinámica, usando el mismo objeto que te regresa `getElementById()` para valores iniciales desde un archivo css tienes que usar `window.getComputedStyle(x).display`

Answer (score 1):

te muestro un código que permite mostrar una alerta creada con CSS, utilizando una función de JavaScript, en el código explico a grandes rasgos de que se trata cada fragmento:

```js
// Cuando el usuario cliclea el <div>, el popup se abre
function mostrarMensaje() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Contenedor del popup */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* pop-up actual */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Muestra del Pop-up*/
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Cambio para mostrar/ocultar el contenedor del pop-up */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Animación del pop-up */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<center>
<br><br><br>
<button class="popup" onclick="mostrarMensaje()">Agregar al carrito
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">¡Producto agregado con éxito!</span>
</button>
</center>
```

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: lo copie exactamente y sigue si funcionarme

Comment: Ejecutalo aquí, funciona a la perfección. ¿Lo estás ejecutando a través de un servidor de pruebas (`localhost/blablabla`) o a través del archivo (`C://bla/bla/bla`)?

Answer (score 1):

El error es que al acceder al elemento por medio de su `id` e intentar acceder a `style` , no lo obtendrá , ya que esta propiedad solo leerá los estilos en línea es decir `<div id="alerta" style="display: none">` ahí si podrá obtener el valor de `display` , pero como el style lo aplica de forma diferente será necesario acceder a [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) para obtener el estilo final.

Su ejemplo quedaría

```js
function mostrar() {
    var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
    if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display=== 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#alerta{
    margin-top:1 0px;
    display: none;
}

#alerta p{
    color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="mostrar()" class="add-to-cart" value="Añadir a compra" />

<div id="alerta" style="display: none">
    <p>Su articulo se ha anadido</p>
</div>
```

Se podría haber realizado esto , haciendo uso de [classList()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) para  alternar la clase mediante `toggle` , añadiendo una clase `.visible` con `display: block !important;` , el `!important` es para se agregue el estilo ya que si no el `id` tendrá "más peso" y seguirá con `display:none;` como fue declarado en el `CSS`.

```js
function mostrar() {
    var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
    x.classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
#alerta{
    margin-top:1 0px;
    display: none;
}

#alerta p{
    color: mediumseagreen;
}
.visible{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="mostrar()" class="add-to-cart" value="Añadir a compra" />
<div id="alerta">
    <p>Su articulo se ha anadido</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @R.Gabriel intentó con el código de mi ejemplo ? , desde aquí funciona correctamente. ¿Muestra algún posible error en consola ? ¿quizá de su demás código que no nos mostró?

Comment: Si , tengo demas codigo, es muy extenso.

Comment: Tengo unos scripts para hacer un quick-view a algunos productos el boton que quiero agregar esta dentro del popup que genera el quick-view

Comment: Me da este error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: (unknown) WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8125/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Los errores que comenta , no están relacionados con su pregunta. No podría ayudar en ese sentido , simplemente me centré en su pregunta y mi respuesta funciona. Los errores quizá podría añadir una nueva pregunta con la descripción y el código necesario y se le brindará el apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente le he añadido al JS `window.addEventListener("load",mostrar);` para que al cargar la página se apliquen las instrucciones de la función `mostrar()`. Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",mostrar);
function mostrar() {
  var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#alerta{
    margin-top:1 0px;
    display: none;
}

#alerta p{
    color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
  <form>
      <input type="button" onclick="mostrar()" class="add-to-cart" value="Anadir a compra" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">


</form>
      <div id="alerta">
          <p>Su articulo se ha anadido</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La function mostrar quedaría asi :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
                          $("#alert").show();
                    });
    });
</script>
```

Utilizando esto te sobraria el onClick="mostrar()" porque ya iría implementado en la función JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma más sencilla que no requiere JavaScript.

Partiendo del siguiente HTML:

```
<button class="boton">Añadir
<span class="botontext">Su artículo se ha añadido</span>
</button>
```

Implementamos el siguiente CSS:

```
    .boton {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .boton .botontext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 160px;


  background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
.boton .botontext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.boton:focus > .botontext {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

Ahora en teoría ya funcionaría todo sin necesidad de utilizar JS.